# implementing lexical, syntatic and semantic analysis

Tags: c, compiler, lex

My program , developed with C using win_flex , implements lexical, syntatic and semantic analysis , given defined grammar rules.

I would like to know if you any suggestion for improving or refactoring this.

Here is my code:

**main.c**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "LEXYY.h"
#include "PARSER.h"
#include "semantic.h"

char *yytext;
FILE *yyin;
int yylex();

void printToken() {
    const char *TokenNames[11] = {
        "PROGRAM", "END",
        "INTEGER", "REAL", "INT_NUMBER", "REAL_NUMBER",
        "ID", "VOID", "RETURN",
        "COMMA", "SEMICOLON",
    };
    char buffer[] = { (char)token->kind, '\0' };
    const char *token_name = token->kind >= PROGRAM ? TokenNames[token->kind - PROGRAM] : buffer;
    token->count = strlen(token->lexeme);

    fprintf(yyout, "Token of kind '%s' was found at line: %d, lexeme: '%s'\n", token_name, token->line, token->lexeme);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int current_token;

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            yyin = fopen("C:\\temp\\test1.txt", "r");
            yyout = fopen("C:\\temp\\test1_200419513_lex.txt", "w");
        }
        else {
            yyin = fopen("C:\\temp\\test2.txt", "r");
            yyout = fopen("C:\\temp\\test2_200419513_lex.txt", "w");
        }
        if (yyin == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot find file.\nPlease use standard input.\n");
            yyin = stdin;
        }
        if (yyout == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open output file.\n");
            yyout = stdout;
        }
        initLexer();
        while ((current_token = yylex()) != 0) {
            create_and_store_token(current_token, (char *)yytext, line_number);
            printToken();
        }

        if (i == 1) {
            yyout = fopen("C:\\temp\\test1_200419513_syntatic.txt", "w");
        }
        else {
            yyout = fopen("C:\\temp\\test2_200419513_syntatic.txt", "w");
        }
        if (yyout == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open output file.\n");
            yyout = stdout;
        }
        if (lexer_errors) {
            fprintf(yyout, "Detected Errors by lexical analysis.\nPlease first fix lexical error.\n");
            continue;
        }
        parser();

        if (i == 1) {
            yyout = fopen("C:\\temp\\test1_200419513_semantic.txt", "w");
        }
        else {
            yyout = fopen("C:\\temp\\test2_200419513_semantic.txt", "w");
        }
        if (yyout == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open output file.\n");
            yyout = stdout;
        }
        if (parser_errors) {
            fprintf(yyout, "Detected Errors by syntatic analysis.\nPlease first fix syntax error.\n");
            continue;
        }
        semantic();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

**LEXYY.Y**

```
program : PROGRAM var_definitions ';' statements END func_definitions
        ;

var_definitions : var_definition
                | var_definition ';' var_definitions
                ;

var_definition : type variables_list
               ;

type : REAL
     | INTEGER
     ;

variables_list : variable
               | variables_list ',' variable
               ;

variable : ID
         | ID '[' INT_NUMBER ']'
         ;

func_definitions : func_definition
                 | func_definitions func_definition
                 ;

func_definition : returned_type ID '(' param_definitions ')' block
                ;

returned_type : VOID
              | type
              ;

param_definitions : /* empty */
                  | var_definitions
                  ;

block : '{' var_definitions ';' statements '}'
      ;

statements : statement ';'
           | statement ';' statements
           ;

statement : variable '=' expression
          | block
          | RETURN
          | RETURN expression
          | function_call
          ;

function_call : ID '(' parameters_list ')'
              ;

parameters_list : /* empty */
                | variables_list
                ;

expression : INT_NUMBER
           | REAL_NUMBER
           | variable
           | ID ar_op expression
           ;

ar_op : '*'
      | '/'
      ;
```

**LEXYY.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct YYTYPE {
    int kind;
    char *lexeme;
    int line;
    int count;
    struct YYTYPE *next;
    struct YYTYPE *prev;
} YYSTYPE;

YYSTYPE *token;
YYSTYPE *tokens;
int line_number;
int lexer_errors;

void initLexer();
void create_and_store_token(int, char *, int);

#define PROGRAM 256
#define END 257
#define INTEGER 258
#define REAL 259
#define INT_NUMBER 260
#define REAL_NUMBER 261
#define ID 262
#define VOID 263
#define RETURN 264
#define COMMA 265
#define SEMICOLON 266

YYSTYPE *next_token();
YYSTYPE *back_token();
int match(int);

int type();
int ar_op();
int returned_type();
int not_var_definitions();
int not_statements();
```

**LEXYY.C**

```
%option nounistd
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include "LEXYY.h"
#define isatty _isatty
#define fileno _fileno
void initLexer();
void create_and_store_token(int, char *, int);
void errorPrint(char);
void illegalError(const char *, const char *);
%}

WHITESPACE          ([ \t]+)
NEWLINE             (\r|\n|\r\n)
COMMENT             ("--"[^\r\n]*)
ID                  ([A-Za-z]([_]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)
ILLEGALID           ([_][A-Za-z0-9_]*|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*[_]|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z]([_]*[A-Za-z0-9]*)*)
INTEGER             (0|[0-9]+)
REAL                (0\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
WRONGNUMBER         ([0][0-9]+|[0][0-9]+[.][0-9]*|[.][0-9]+|[0-9]+[.])
OPERATOR            ([*/=])
SEPARATION          ([[\]{}\(\)])

%%

{NEWLINE}           { line_number++; }
{WHITESPACE}+       {}
{COMMENT}           {}

"program"           { return PROGRAM; }
"end"               { return END; }
"real"              { return REAL; }
"integer"           { return INTEGER; }
"void"              { return VOID; }
"return"            { return RETURN; }
{INTEGER}           { return INT_NUMBER; }
{REAL}              { return REAL_NUMBER; }
{WRONGNUMBER}       { illegalError(yytext, "Number"); }
","                 { return COMMA; }
";"                 { return SEMICOLON; }

{ID}                { return ID; }
{ILLEGALID}         { illegalError(yytext, "ID"); }

{OPERATOR}          { return yytext[0]; }
{SEPARATION}        { return yytext[0]; }

.                   { errorPrint(yytext[0]); }

%%

void initLexer() {
    line_number = 1;
    lexer_errors = 0;
    tokens = NULL;
    token = NULL;
}

void create_and_store_token(int kind, char *lexeme, int line) {
    if (token == NULL) {
        tokens = (YYSTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(YYSTYPE));
        token = tokens;
        token->next = NULL;
        token->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        token->next = (YYSTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(YYSTYPE));
        token->next->next = NULL;
        token->next->prev = token;
        token = token->next;
    }
    token->kind = kind;
    token->line = line;
    token->lexeme = (char *)malloc(sizeof(lexeme) + 1);
#ifdef _WIN32
    strcpy_s(token->lexeme, strlen(lexeme) + 1, lexeme);
#else
    strcpy(token->lexeme, lexeme);
#endif
}

YYSTYPE *next_token() {
    if (token) 
        return (token = token->next);
    return NULL;
}

YYSTYPE *back_token() {
    if (token) 
        return (token = token->prev);
    return NULL;
}

int match(int kind) {
    if (token && token->kind == kind) 
        return kind;
    return 0;
}

int type() {
    return (match(REAL) ? REAL : match(INTEGER));
}

int ar_op() {
    if (match('*') || match('/')) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int returned_type() {
    return (match(VOID) ? VOID : type());
}

int not_var_definitions() {
    int flag = 0;
    if (!token) 
        flag = 1;
    else if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (match('=') || match('('))
            flag = 2;

        if (match('[')) {
            next_token();
            next_token();
            next_token();
            if (match('=') || match('('))
                flag = 2;

            back_token();
            back_token();
            back_token();
        }
        back_token();
    }

    else 
        flag = 3;
    return flag;

}

int not_statements() {
    if (!token) 
        return 1;
    if (!match(ID) && !match(RETURN) && !match('{')) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void errorPrint(char ch) {
    fprintf(yyout, "The character '%c' at line: %d does not begin any legal token in the language.\n", ch, line_number);
}

void illegalError(const char *text, const char *type) {
    fprintf(yyout, "Illegal %s '%s' was found at line %d\n", type, text, line_number);
}
```

**parser.c**

```
#pragma once

#include "LEXYY.h"

int parser_errors, recovery;
FILE *yyout;

void error_handle(char *, YYSTYPE *);
void print_token(char *, YYSTYPE *);

int parser();
void var_definitions();
void var_definition();
void variables_list();
void variable();
void statements();
void statement();
void function_call();
void parameters_list();
int expression();
void block();
void func_definitions();
void func_definition();
void param_definitions();
```

**parser.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PARSER.h"

void error_handle(char *expected, YYSTYPE *token) {
    if (token) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Error: Expected token is { %s }, but actual token is [ %s ] at line %d\n", expected, token->lexeme, token->line);
        parser_errors++;
        recovery = 1;
    }
}

void print_token(char *str, YYSTYPE *token) {
    if (token) 
        fprintf(yyout, str, token->lexeme, token->line);
}

int parser() {
    parser_errors = 0;
    recovery = 0;
    token = tokens;

    if (!token) 
        return 0;

    fprintf(yyout, "Starting Program...\n");

    if (!match(PROGRAM)) {
        error_handle("program", token);
        recovery = 0;
    }
    else 
        print_token("[ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token();

    var_definitions();

    statements();

    if (!match(END)) {
        error_handle("end", token);
        recovery = 0;
    }
    else 
        print_token("[ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token();

    func_definitions();

    return parser_errors;
}

void var_definitions() {
    if (!type()) 
        if (not_var_definitions()) 
            return;

    fprintf(yyout, "Variable Definitions...\n");

    while (token) {
        if (!type()) {
            if (not_var_definitions()) {
                recovery = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        var_definition();
        if (match(')'))
            break;
        if (!match(SEMICOLON))
            error_handle(";", token);
        next_token();
    }
}

void var_definition() {
    if (type()) 
        print_token("Variable Type [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    else if (!type()) 
        error_handle("integer, real", token);
    next_token();
    variables_list();
}

void variables_list() {
    int error;
    do {
        error = not_var_definitions();
        variable();
        if (error == 2) {
            error_handle(",", token);
            while (!match(COMMA) && !match(SEMICOLON)) next_token();
            recovery = 0;
        }
    } while (match(COMMA) && next_token());
}

void variable() {
    token->lexeme[token->count] = '\0';
    if (!match(ID)) {
        if (recovery) {
            while (!match(ID) && !match(COMMA) && !match(SEMICOLON)) next_token();
            recovery = 0;
            if (!match(ID)) return;
        }
        else error_handle("Variable Name(id)", token);
    }
    next_token();
    if (match('[')) {
        if (!recovery) {
            back_token();
            if (token) fprintf(yyout, "Array Variable %s\n", token->lexeme);
            next_token();
        }
        next_token();
        if (!match(INT_NUMBER)) {
            error_handle("int number", token);
        }
        else print_token("Array Size [%s] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
        if (!match(']') && token) {
            if (recovery) {
                while (!match(']')) next_token();
                recovery = 0;
            }
            else error_handle("]", token);
        }
        next_token();
    }
    else {
        if (!recovery) {
            back_token();
            print_token("Variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
        }
    }
}

void statements() {
    if (not_statements()) return;

    fprintf(yyout, "Statement List...\n");

    while (!not_statements()) {
        statement();
        if (!match(SEMICOLON)) {
            if (recovery) {
                while (!match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{') && !match(END))
                    if (!next_token()) 
                        break;
                recovery = 0;
            }
            else 
                error_handle(";", token);
        }
        if (match(END)) 
            break;
        if (match('{')) 
            continue;
        next_token();
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) 
            next_token();
    }
}

void statement() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Statement...\n");

    if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (match('(')) {
            back_token();
            function_call();
        }
        else {
            back_token();
            fprintf(yyout, "Variable Assignment...\n");

            variable();

      if (!match('=')) {
        if (!match(SEMICOLON)) 
            error_handle("=", token);
        if (recovery) {
            while (!match('=') && !match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{') && !match(END)) 
                next_token();
                recovery = 0;
            if (match(SEMICOLON) || match('{') || match(END)) 
                return;
            print_token("Assign Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        }
     } 
     else 
        print_token("Assign Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

            next_token();
            if (!expression()) {
                if (match(END) || match('{')) 
                    return;
                error_handle("int number, real number, id", token);
                next_token();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (match(RETURN)) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Return Statement...\n");
        next_token();
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) fprintf(yyout, "Empty Statement\n");
        else {
            if (!expression()) 
                error_handle("ID, int number, real number", token);
            expression();
        }
    }
    else if (match('{')) {
        block();
    }
}

void function_call() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Function Call...\n");
    print_token("Function Name [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token(); 
    next_token();
    parameters_list();

    if (!match(')')) {
        error_handle(", or )", token);
        next_token();
        while (!match(')') && !match(SEMICOLON)) 
            next_token();
        back_token();
    }
    next_token();
}

void parameters_list() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Parameters List...\n");

    if (match(')')) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Empty Parameter\n");
    }
    else 
        variables_list();
}

int expression() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Expression...\n");

    if (recovery) {
        while (!match(INT_NUMBER) && !match(REAL_NUMBER) && !match(ID) && !match('{')) next_token();
        recovery = 0;
        if (match('{')) 
            return 0;
    }

    if (match(INT_NUMBER)) {
        print_token("int number [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
    }
    else if (match(REAL_NUMBER)) {
        print_token("real number [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
    }
    else if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (ar_op()) {
            back_token();
            print_token("ID [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
            print_token("Arithmetic Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
            if (!expression()) {
                error_handle("int number, real number, id", token);
                next_token();
            }
        }
        else {
            back_token();
            variable();
        }
    }
    else 
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

void block() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Block Statement...\n");

    if (!match('{')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle("{", token);
    }
    next_token();

    var_definitions();

    back_token();
    if (!match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle(";", token);
    }

    next_token();

    statements();

    if (!match('}')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle("}", token);
    }

    next_token();
}

void func_definitions() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Function Definitions List...\n");

    while (token) 
        func_definition();
}

void func_definition() {
    if (!returned_type()) {
        error_handle("integer, real, void", token);
        while (!returned_type() && !match(ID)) 
            next_token();
    }

    recovery = 0;

    fprintf(yyout, "Function Definition...\n");
    if (returned_type()) 
        print_token("Return Type [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    else 
        error_handle("integer, real, void", token);
    next_token();

    if (!match(ID)) 
        error_handle("id", token);
    else 
        print_token("Function Name [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    next_token();

    if (!match('(')) 
        error_handle("(", token);
    next_token();

    param_definitions();

    if (!match(')')) 
        error_handle(")", token);
    next_token();

    block();
    if (recovery) {
        while (!match('}')) next_token();
        next_token();
        recovery = 0;
    }
}

void param_definitions() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Parameter definitions List...\n");
    if (match(')')) 
        fprintf(yyout, "Empty Parameter\n");
    else 
        var_definitions();
```

**semantic.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "LEXYY.h"

typedef struct SCOPES {
    struct SCOPES *parent;
    struct SCOPES *first_child;     /*for right */
    struct SCOPES *next_sibling;    /*for left*/
    struct SYMBOLS *symbols;
} SCOPE;

typedef struct SYMBOLS {
    char *name;
    int type;
    int size;
    int initialized;
    int used;
    int line;
    struct SYMBOLS *next;
    struct SYMBOLS *prev;
} SYMBOL;

typedef struct FUNCTIONS {
    char *name;
    int returnd_type;
    int param_number;
    int line;
    struct SYMBOLS *params;
    struct SCOPES *scope;
    struct FUNCTIONS *prev_func;
    struct FUNCTIONS *next_func;
} FUNCTION;

SCOPE *root;

FUNCTION *func;

int semantic_errors, semantic_warnings;
FILE *yyout;

int return_statement;

FUNCTION *find_func(char *);
SYMBOL *find_symbol(SCOPE *, char *, SYMBOL *);

void semantic_error_handle(char *, char *, int);

int semantic();

FUNCTION *get_function_list();
FUNCTION *get_function();

SYMBOL *semantic_var_definitions(SCOPE *, SYMBOL *, int);
SYMBOL *semantic_var_definition(SCOPE *);
SYMBOL *semantic_vars_list(SCOPE *, int);
SYMBOL *semantic_var(SCOPE *, int);
SCOPE *semantic_statements(SCOPE *, int, SYMBOL *);
void semantic_statement(SCOPE *, int, SYMBOL *);
void semantic_function_call(SCOPE *, SYMBOL *);
int semantic_expression(SCOPE *, SYMBOL *);
SCOPE *semantic_block(SCOPE *, int, SYMBOL *);
void semantic_func_definitions();
void semantic_func_definition(FUNCTION *f);

void check_unused_in_scope(SCOPE *);
void check_unused_in_function(FUNCTION *);
```

**semantic.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "semantic.h"

/*find function definition*/
FUNCTION *find_func(char *name) {
    FUNCTION *f = func;
    while (f && strcmp(f->name, name))
        f = f->prev_func;
    return f;
}

/*finding variable definition*/
SYMBOL *find_symbol(SCOPE *scope, char *name, SYMBOL *params) {
    SYMBOL *symbols;
    /*if function definition, searching in function parameters*/
    if (params) {
        symbols = params;
        while (symbols) {
            if (!strcmp(symbols->name, name)) 
                return symbols;
            symbols = symbols->next;
        }
    }
    if (!scope) 
        return NULL;
    /*searchinf in scope variables*/
    symbols = scope->symbols;
    while (symbols) {
        if (!strcmp(symbols->name, name)) 
            return symbols;
        symbols = symbols->next;
    }
    return find_symbol(scope->parent, name, NULL);
}

void semantic_error_handle(char *str, char *name, int line) {
    fprintf(yyout, str, name, line);
    semantic_errors++;
}

/*processing semantic analysis*/
int semantic() {
    semantic_errors = semantic_warnings = 0;
    token = tokens;
    if (!token) 
        return 0;

    //preload function definitions for function call
    while (!match(END)) 
        next_token();

    func = get_function_list();

    token = tokens;
    next_token();

    /*creating new scope for main program*/
    root = (SCOPE *)malloc(sizeof(SCOPE));
    root->parent = root->first_child = root->next_sibling = NULL;
    root->symbols = NULL;

    /*get variable definitions in current scope*/
    root->symbols = semantic_var_definitions(root, NULL, 1);

    /*analysing statements and get sub scope*/
    root->first_child = semantic_statements(root, VOID, NULL);

    next_token();

    check_unused_in_scope(root);

    semantic_func_definitions();

    if (!semantic_errors) 
        fprintf(yyout, "Semantic analysis success!\n");

    return semantic_errors;
}

/*getting function definition list before start analysis*/
FUNCTION *get_function_list() {
    FUNCTION *functions = NULL;
    next_token();
    while (token) {
        if (functions) {
            functions->next_func = get_function();
            functions->next_func->prev_func = functions;
            functions = functions->next_func;
        }
        else 
            functions = get_function();
    }
    return functions;
}

/*getting function definition before start of analysis*/
FUNCTION *get_function() {
    FUNCTION *f = (FUNCTION *)malloc(sizeof(FUNCTION));
    SYMBOL *temp;
    f->next_func = f->prev_func = NULL;
    f->scope = NULL;
    int block_number = 0;
    f->returnd_type = returned_type();
    next_token();
    f->name = token->lexeme;
    f->line = token->line;
    next_token();
    next_token();

    /*getting function parameters list and number*/
    f->params = semantic_var_definitions(NULL, NULL, 0);
    f->param_number = 0;
    temp = f->params;
    while (temp) {
        f->param_number++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    next_token();

    do {
        if (match('{')) 
            block_number++;
        if (match('}')) 
            block_number--;
        next_token();
    } while (block_number);

    return f;
}

/*get variables definitions*/
SYMBOL *semantic_var_definitions(SCOPE *scope, SYMBOL *params, int check) {
    SYMBOL *symbols = NULL, *temp = NULL, *temp1;

    /*creating symbol table for current scope*/
    while (token) {
        if (!type()) 
            break;
        if (symbols) {
            while (temp->next) temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = semantic_var_definition(scope);
            temp->next->prev = temp;
        }
        else {
            temp = symbols = semantic_var_definition(scope);
            while (temp->next) temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (match(')')) 
            break;
        next_token();
    }
    /*after getting variables, checking for duplicated definitions. if function definition, checking function parameters*/
    if (params) {
        temp = symbols;
        while (temp) {
            /*if varialble name is function name, then error*/
            if (find_func(temp->name)) {
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot use function name [ %s ] with varaible at line [ %d ]\n", temp->name, temp->line);
                if (scope) {
                    if (temp->prev) {
                        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                        if (temp->next) 
                            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                        temp1 = temp;
                        temp = temp->next;
                        free(temp1);
                    }
                    else {
                        symbols = temp->next;
                        if (symbols) 
                            symbols->prev = NULL;
                        free(temp);
                        temp = symbols;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            temp1 = params;
            /*check in parameter definitions*/
            while (temp1) {
                if (!strcmp(temp->name, temp1->name)) 
                    break;
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            /*if duplicated definition*/
            if (temp1) {
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Duplicated variable [ %s ] declaration with parameters at line %d\n", temp->name, temp->line);
                if (scope) {
                    if (temp->prev) {
                        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                        if (temp->next) 
                            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                        temp1 = temp;
                        temp = temp->next;
                        free(temp1);
                    }
                    else {
                        symbols = temp->next;
                        if (symbols) 
                            symbols->prev = NULL;
                        free(temp);
                        temp = symbols;
                    }
                }
                else
                    temp = temp->next;
            }
            else 
                temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    /*checking scope variables*/
    if (check) {
        temp = symbols;
        while (temp) {
            /*if varialble name is function name -  error*/
            if (find_func(temp->name)) {
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot use function name [ %s ] with varaible at line [ %d ]\n", temp->name, temp->line);
                if (scope) {
                    if (temp->prev) {
                        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                        if (temp->next) 
                            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                        temp1 = temp;
                        temp = temp->next;
                        free(temp1);
                    }
                    else {
                        symbols = temp->next;
                        if (symbols) 
                            symbols->prev = NULL;
                        free(temp);
                        temp = symbols;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (!temp->size) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Array size cannot be zero at line %s%d\n", "", temp->line);
            temp1 = temp->prev;

            while (temp1) {
                if (!strcmp(temp->name, temp1->name)) 
                    break;
                temp1 = temp1->prev;
            }

            if (temp1) {
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Duplicated variable [ %s ] declaration within same scope at line %d\n", temp->name, temp->line);
                if (scope) {
                    if (temp->prev) {
                        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                        if (temp->next) 
                            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                        temp1 = temp;
                        temp = temp->next;
                        free(temp1);
                    }
                    else {
                        symbols = temp->next;
                        if (symbols) 
                            symbols->prev = NULL;
                        free(temp);
                        temp = symbols;
                    }
                }
                else 
                    temp = temp->next;
            }
            else 
                temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return symbols;
}

/*getting variable definition*/
SYMBOL *semantic_var_definition(SCOPE *scope) {
    int var_type = type();
    next_token();

    return semantic_vars_list(scope, var_type);
}

/*getting variables list, each variable separated by comma, and insert into symbol table*/
SYMBOL *semantic_vars_list(SCOPE *scope, int var_type) {
    SYMBOL *symbols = NULL, *temp = NULL;

    do {
        if (symbols) {
            temp->next = semantic_var(scope, var_type);
            temp->next->prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        else 
            temp = symbols = semantic_var(scope, var_type);
    } while (match(COMMA) && next_token());

    return symbols;
}

/*getting variables separated by comma and make symbol item for symbol table*/
SYMBOL *semantic_var(SCOPE *scope, int var_type) {
    SYMBOL *symbol;
    if (!match(ID))
        return NULL;

    symbol = (SYMBOL *)malloc(sizeof(SYMBOL));
    symbol->type = var_type;
    symbol->name = token->lexeme;
    symbol->line = token->line;
    symbol->initialized = 0;
    symbol->used = 0;
    next_token();

    /*check if array varaible*/
    if (match('[')) {
        next_token();
        symbol->size = atoi(token->lexeme);
        next_token(); next_token();
    }
    else 
        symbol->size = -1;

    symbol->next = symbol->prev = NULL;

    return symbol;
}

/*analysis statements and get sub scopes*/
SCOPE *semantic_statements(SCOPE *parent, int return_type, SYMBOL *params) {
    SCOPE *scope = NULL, *temp = NULL;

    while (!not_statements()) {
        /* new scope for sub scope*/
        if (!scope) {
            scope = (SCOPE *)malloc(sizeof(SCOPE));
            scope->parent = parent;
            scope->first_child = scope->next_sibling = NULL;
            scope->symbols = NULL;
        }

        /*analysising each statementand get symbols for sub scope*/
        semantic_statement(scope, return_type, params);
        if (match(END)) 
            break;
        if (match('{')) 
            continue;
        next_token();
    }
    return scope;
}

/*analysinf each statement*/
void semantic_statement(SCOPE *scope, int return_type, SYMBOL *params) {
    SYMBOL *symbol, *cur_symbol;
    FUNCTION *f_temp = NULL;
    int type, line;

    /*if current statement is assignment or function call   */
    if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        /*if function call*/
        if (match('(')) {
            back_token();

            semantic_function_call(scope, params);
        }

        /*assignment*/
        else {
            back_token();
            /*getting variable for assignment*/
            symbol = semantic_var(scope, 0);
            /*check if current variable is declaration*/
            cur_symbol = find_symbol(scope, symbol->name, params);

            /*if current variable is declaration*/
            if (cur_symbol) {
                cur_symbol->initialized = 1;
                cur_symbol->used = 1;
                symbol->type = cur_symbol->type;

                /*if variable is arra*/
                if (cur_symbol->size > -1) {
                    /*check array size for array index  */
                    if (symbol->size > cur_symbol->size) 
                        semantic_error_handle("Error: Exceed bound of array [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
                    else if (symbol->size <  0) 
                        semantic_error_handle("Error: Expressions can't refer to entire array [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
                }

                else if (symbol->size > -1) 
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Not array variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
            }
            /*if current variable is not declared*/
            else {
                f_temp = find_func(symbol->name);
                /*if symbole is function*/
                if (f_temp) 
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot assign to function name [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
                /*undefined variable*/
                else
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Undefined variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
            }

            next_token();
            type = semantic_expression(scope, params);
            /*if erro type, then error*/
            if (!type) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot eval expression type [ %s ] at line %d\n", "error_type", symbol->line);
            /*if type mismatch,  then error */
            if (!f_temp && (!type || (symbol->type != type && !(symbol->type == REAL && type == INTEGER)))) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot assign variable [ %s ] type mismatch at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
        }
    }
    /*return statement*/
    else if (match(RETURN)) {
        next_token();
        line = token->line;
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) {
            if (return_type != VOID) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Return type mismatch %s at line %d\n", "", line);
        }
        /*if return type mismatch   */
        else {
            type = semantic_expression(scope, params);
            if (return_type == VOID || (return_type != type && return_type != REAL && type != INTEGER)) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Return type mismatch %s at line %d\n", "", line);
        }
        return_statement = 1;
    }
    /*block statement*/
    else if (match('{')) 
        semantic_block(scope, return_type, params);
}

/*analysis function call*/
void semantic_function_call(SCOPE *scope, SYMBOL *params) {
    /*check function definition*/
    FUNCTION *f = find_func(token->lexeme), *f_temp;
    SYMBOL *actual_params, *func_params = NULL, *cur_symbol;
    int param_number = 0, call_line = token->line;

    if (!f) 
        semantic_error_handle("Error: Undefined function [ %s ] at line %d\n", token->lexeme, token->line);
    next_token(); next_token();
    /*getting parameters list of function call*/
    actual_params = semantic_vars_list(NULL, 0);
    /*get parameters list of function definition*/
    if (f) 
        func_params = f->params;
    /*compare function call parameters with function definition parameters*/
    while (actual_params) {
        param_number++;
        /*checking parameter of funciton call in scopes*/
        cur_symbol = find_symbol(scope, actual_params->name, params);
        /*if found*/
        if (cur_symbol) {
            cur_symbol->used = 1;
            /*if variable is array*/
            if (cur_symbol->size > -1) {
                if (actual_params->size > cur_symbol->size) 
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Exceed bound of array [ %s ] at line %d\n", actual_params->name, actual_params->line);
                else if (actual_params->size < -1) 
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Expressions can't refer to entire array [ %s ] at line %d\n", actual_params->name, actual_params->line);
            }
            /*if variable is not array but it's as sucj, then error*/
            else if (actual_params->size > -1) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Not array variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", actual_params->name, actual_params->line);

            /*if variable type of function call doesn't mismatch with varaible type of function definition*/
            if (func_params && cur_symbol->type != func_params->type && !(cur_symbol->type == INTEGER && func_params->type == REAL)) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Variable type [ %s ] does not match with function parameters at line %d\n", cur_symbol->type == INTEGER ? "integer" : "real", actual_params->line);
        }
        /*if not found*/
        else {
            f_temp = find_func(actual_params->name);
            /*if symbole is function*/
            if (f_temp) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot use function name as variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", actual_params->name, actual_params->line);
            /*undefined variable*/
            else 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Undefined variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", actual_params->name, actual_params->line);
        }
        actual_params = actual_params->next;
        if (func_params) 
            func_params = func_params->next;
        if (actual_params) 
            free(actual_params->prev);
    }
    /*check function parameters number*/
    if (f && param_number > f->param_number) 
        semantic_error_handle("Error: Too much parameters for [ %s ] at line %d\n", f->name, call_line);
    else if (f && param_number < f->param_number) 
        semantic_error_handle("Error: Too few parameters for [ %s ] at line %d\n", f->name, call_line);
    next_token();
}

/*analysis expression and get its type*/
int semantic_expression(SCOPE *scope, SYMBOL *params) {
    SYMBOL *symbol, *cur_symbol;
    FUNCTION *f_temp;
    int type = 0;
    /*int number is integer*/

    if (match(INT_NUMBER)) {
        next_token();
        type = INTEGER;
    }
    /*real number is real*/
    else if (match(REAL_NUMBER)) {
        next_token();
        type = REAL;
    }
    else if (match(ID)) {
        symbol = semantic_var(scope, 0);
        cur_symbol = find_symbol(scope, symbol->name, params);
        /*if it is declared*/
        if (cur_symbol) {
            cur_symbol->used = 1;
            symbol->type = cur_symbol->type;
            type = symbol->type;
            /*if variable is array*/
            if (cur_symbol->size > -1) {
                /*checking array size*/
                if (symbol->size > cur_symbol->size) 
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Exceed bound of array [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
                else if (symbol->size < 0) 
                    semantic_error_handle("Error: Expressions can't refer to entire array [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
            }
            /*if variable is not array but it's used with as such- then error*/
            else if (symbol->size > -1) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Not array variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);

        }
        /*if  declaration of variable is not found*/
        else {
            f_temp = find_func(symbol->name);
            if (f_temp) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Cannot use function name as variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
            else 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Undefined variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
        }
        /*if arithmetic operation, geting next expression's type*/
        if (ar_op()) {
            next_token();
            type = semantic_expression(scope, params);
            if (type && (symbol->type == REAL || !symbol->type)) 
                type = symbol->type;
        }
    }
    return type;
}

/*analysing block and get sub scope */
SCOPE *semantic_block(SCOPE *parent, int return_type, SYMBOL *params) {
    /*createing new scope for sub scope*/
    SCOPE *scope = (SCOPE *)malloc(sizeof(SCOPE)), *temp = parent;
    scope->parent = parent;
    scope->first_child = scope->next_sibling = NULL;
    next_token();
    /*getting variables list in sub scope*/
    scope->symbols = semantic_var_definitions(scope, params, 1);
    /*analysing statements in sub scope*/
    scope->first_child = semantic_statements(scope, return_type, params);
    next_token();
    /*linking with parent scope*/
    if (temp) {
        if (temp->first_child) {
            while (temp->next_sibling->next_sibling) temp = temp->next_sibling;
            temp->next_sibling = scope;
        }
        else 
            temp->first_child = scope;
    }
    return scope;
}

/*analysing function definitions*/
void semantic_func_definitions() {
    FUNCTION *f;
    func = NULL;

    /*get function definitions list*/
    while (token) {
        f = (FUNCTION *)malloc(sizeof(FUNCTION));
        f->next_func = f->prev_func = NULL;
        if (func) {
            func->next_func = f;
            func->next_func->prev_func = func;
            func = func->next_func;
        }
        else 
            func = f;
        semantic_func_definition(f);
    }
}

/*analysing function definition and getting scopes for each function*/
void semantic_func_definition(FUNCTION *f) {
    FUNCTION *f_temp = func->prev_func;
    SYMBOL *temp;
    /*type of function*/
    f->returnd_type = returned_type();
    next_token();
    f->name = token->lexeme;
    f->line = token->line;
    /*checking if  definition deplicated*/
    while (f_temp) {
        if (!strcmp(f->name, f_temp->name))
            break;
        f_temp = f_temp->prev_func;
    }
    if (f_temp) 
        semantic_error_handle("Error: Function [ %s ] overloading at line %d\n", f->name, f->line);

    next_token(); 
    next_token();
    if (token->line == 100)
        token->line = token->line;
    f->params = semantic_var_definitions(NULL, NULL, 1);
    f->param_number = 0;
    temp = f->params;
    while (temp) {
        f->param_number++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    next_token();

    return_statement = 0;
    /*sub scope of this function*/
    f->scope = semantic_block(NULL, f->returnd_type, f->params);

    if (!return_statement && f->returnd_type != VOID)
        semantic_error_handle("Error: No return statement in function [ %s ]\n", f->name, 0);


    /*checking if any variable is not used in function*/
    check_unused_in_function(f);
}

/*check if any variables are not declared in scope*/
void check_unused_in_scope(SCOPE *root) {
    if (!root) 
        return;
    while (root->symbols) {
        if (!root->symbols->used) {
            semantic_error_handle("Error: Unused variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", root->symbols->name, root->symbols->line);
        }
        root->symbols = root->symbols->next;
    }
    if (root->first_child) 
        check_unused_in_scope(root->first_child);
    if (root->next_sibling) 
        check_unused_in_scope(root->next_sibling);
}

/*checking if any variables are not declared in function*/
void check_unused_in_function(FUNCTION *func) {
    if (func->params) {
        SYMBOL *symbol = func->params, *temp;
        while (symbol) {
            temp = symbol->prev;
            while (temp) {
                if (!strcmp(temp->name, symbol->name))
                    break;
                temp = temp->prev;
            }
            if (!temp && !symbol->used) 
                semantic_error_handle("Error: Unused variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", symbol->name, symbol->line);
            symbol = symbol->next;
        }
    }
    if (func->scope) 
        check_unused_in_scope(func->scope);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Was any of the code generated by tools such as `Lex` or `Flex` for the lexical analyzer or `YACC` or `Bison` for the parser? If so please indicte which parts.

Comment: @pacmaninbw flex

Comment: Does this program build properly for you? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes