# implementing parser - improvment

Tags: c, parsing, lexical-analysis

I have been trying to develop a program which implements a parser, i.e., syntactic analysis.

Here is what I have done so far:

**parser.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.h"

void error_handle(char *expected, YYSTYPE *token) {
    if (token) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Error: Expected token is { %s }, but actual token is [ %s ] at line %d\n", expected, token->lexeme, token->line);
        recovery = 1;
    }
}

void print_token(char *str, YYSTYPE *token) {
    if (token) 
        fprintf(yyout, str, token->lexeme, token->line);
}



int parser() {
    parser_errors = 0;
    recovery = 0;
    token = tokens;

    if (!token)
        return 0;

    fprintf(yyout, "Starting Program...\n");

    if (!match(PROGRAM)) {
        error_handle("program", token);
        recovery = 0;
    }
    else
        print_token("[ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token();

    var_definitions();

    statements();

    if (!match(END)) {
        error_handle("end", token);
        recovery = 0;
    }
    else
        print_token("[ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token();

    func_definitions();

    return parser_errors;
}


void var_definitions() {
    if (!type()) 
        if (not_var_definitions()) 
            return;

    fprintf(yyout, "Variable Definitions...\n");

    while (token) {
        if (!type()) {
            if (not_var_definitions()) {
                recovery = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        var_definition();
        if (match(')'))
            break;
        if (!match(SEMICOLON))
            error_handle(";", token);
        next_token();
    }
}

void var_definition() {
    if (type()) 
        print_token("Variable Type [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    else if (!type()) 
        error_handle("integer, real", token);
    next_token();
    variables_list();
}

void variables_list() {
    int error;
    do {
        error = not_var_definitions();
        variable();
        if (error == 2) {
            error_handle(",", token);
            while (!match(COMMA) && !match(SEMICOLON))
                next_token();
            recovery = 0;
        }
    } while (match(COMMA) && next_token());
}

void variable() {
    token->lexeme[token->count] = '\0';
    if (!match(ID)) {
        if (recovery) {
            while (!match(ID) && !match(COMMA) && !match(SEMICOLON)) 
                next_token();
            recovery = 0;
            if (!match(ID)) return;
        }
        else error_handle("Variable Name(id)", token);
    }
    next_token();
    if (match('[')) {
        if (!recovery) {
            back_token();
            if (token) 
                fprintf(yyout, "Array Variable %s\n", token->lexeme);
            next_token();
        }
        next_token();
        if (!match(INT_NUMBER)) {
            error_handle("int number", token);
        }
        else 
            print_token("Array Size [%s] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
        if (!match(']') && token) {
            if (recovery) {
                while (!match(']'))
                    next_token();
                recovery = 0;
            }
            else 
                error_handle("]", token);
        }
        next_token();
    }
    else {
        if (!recovery) {
            back_token();
            print_token("Variable [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
        }
    }
}

void statements() {
    if (not_statements()) 
        return;

    fprintf(yyout, "Statement List...\n");

    while (!not_statements()) {
        statement();
        if (!match(SEMICOLON)) {
            if (recovery) {
                while (!match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{') && !match(END))
                    if (!next_token()) 
                        break;
                recovery = 0;
            }
            else 
                error_handle(";", token);
        }
        if (match(END)) 
            break;
        if (match('{')) 
            continue;
        next_token();
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) 
            next_token();
    }
}

void statement() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Statement...\n");

    if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (match('(')) {
            back_token();
            function_call();
        }
        else {
            back_token();
            fprintf(yyout, "Variable Assignment...\n");

            variable();

      if (!match('=')) {
        if (!match(SEMICOLON)) 
            error_handle("=", token);
        if (recovery) {
            while (!match('=') && !match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{') && !match(END)) 
                next_token();
                recovery = 0;
            if (match(SEMICOLON) || match('{') || match(END)) 
                return;
            print_token("Assign Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        }
     } 
     else 
        print_token("Assign Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

            next_token();
            if (!expression()) {
                if (match(END) || match('{')) 
                    return;
                error_handle("int number, real number, id", token);
                next_token();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (match(RETURN)) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Return Statement...\n");
        next_token();
        if (match(SEMICOLON)) 
            fprintf(yyout, "Empty Statement\n");
        else {
            if (!expression()) 
                error_handle("ID, int number, real number", token);
            expression();
        }
    }
    else if (match('{')) 
        block();
}

void function_call() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Function Call...\n");
    print_token("Function Name [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);

    next_token(); 
    next_token();
    parameters_list();

    if (!match(')')) {
        error_handle(", or )", token);
        next_token();
        while (!match(')') && !match(SEMICOLON)) 
            next_token();
        back_token();
    }
    next_token();
}

void parameters_list() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Parameters List...\n");

    if (match(')')) {
        fprintf(yyout, "Empty Parameter\n");
    }
    else 
        variables_list();
}

int expression() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Expression...\n");

    if (recovery) {
        while (!match(INT_NUMBER) && !match(REAL_NUMBER) && !match(ID) && !match('{')) 
            next_token();
        recovery = 0;
        if (match('{')) 
            return 0;
    }

    if (match(INT_NUMBER)) {
        print_token("int number [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
    }
    else if (match(REAL_NUMBER)) {
        print_token("real number [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
        next_token();
    }
    else if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (ar_op()) {
            back_token();
            print_token("ID [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
            print_token("Arithmetic Operator [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
            next_token();
            if (!expression()) {
                error_handle("int number, real number, id", token);
                next_token();
            }
        }
        else {
            back_token();
            variable();
        }
    }
    else 
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

void block() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Block Statement...\n");

    if (!match('{')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle("{", token);
    }
    next_token();

    var_definitions();

    back_token();
    if (!match(SEMICOLON) && !match('{')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle(";", token);
    }

    next_token();

    statements();

    if (!match('}')) {
        if (match(END)) 
            return;
        error_handle("}", token);
    }

    next_token();
}

void func_definitions() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Function Definitions List...\n");

    while (token) 
        func_definition();
}

void func_definition() {
    if (!returned_type()) {
        error_handle("integer, real, void", token);
        while (!returned_type() && !match(ID)) 
            next_token();
    }

    recovery = 0;

    fprintf(yyout, "Function Definition...\n");
    if (returned_type()) 
        print_token("Return Type [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    else 
        error_handle("integer, real, void", token);
    next_token();

    if (!match(ID)) 
        error_handle("id", token);
    else 
        print_token("Function Name [ %s ] at line %d\n", token);
    next_token();

    if (!match('(')) 
        error_handle("(", token);
    next_token();

    param_definitions();

    if (!match(')')) 
        error_handle(")", token);
    next_token();

    block();
    if (recovery) {
        while (!match('}')) next_token();
        next_token();
        recovery = 0;
    }
}

void param_definitions() {
    fprintf(yyout, "Parameter definitions List...\n");
    if (match(')')) 
        fprintf(yyout, "Empty Parameter\n");
    else 
        var_definitions();

}
```

**parser.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "LEXYY.h"

int recovery, parser_errors;
FILE *yyout;

void error_handle(char *, YYSTYPE *);
void print_token(char *, YYSTYPE *);

int parser();
void var_definitions();
void var_definition();
void variables_list();
```

**LEXYY.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct YYTYPE {
    int kind;
    char *lexeme;
    int line;
    int count;
    struct YYTYPE *next;
    struct YYTYPE *prev;
} YYSTYPE;

YYSTYPE *token;
YYSTYPE *tokens;
int line_number;
int lexer_errors;

void initLexer();
void create_and_store_token(int, char *, int);

#define PROGRAM 256
#define END 257
#define INTEGER 258
#define REAL 259
#define INT_NUMBER 260
#define REAL_NUMBER 261
#define ID 262
#define VOID 263
#define RETURN 264
#define COMMA 265
#define SEMICOLON 266

YYSTYPE *next_token();
YYSTYPE *back_token();
int match(int);

int type();
int ar_op();
int returned_type();
int not_var_definitions();
int not_statements();
void variable();
void statements();
void statement();
void function_call();
void parameters_list();
int expression();
void block();
void func_definitions();
void func_definition();
void param_definitions();
```

**LEXYY.c**

```
%option nounistd
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include "LEXYY.h"
#define isatty _isatty
#define fileno _fileno
void initLexer();
void create_and_store_token(int, char *, int);
void errorPrint(char);
void illegalError(const char *, const char *);
%}

WHITESPACE          ([ \t]+)
NEWLINE             (\r|\n|\r\n)
COMMENT             ("--"[^\r\n]*)
ID                  ([A-Za-z]([_]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)
ILLEGALID           ([_][A-Za-z0-9_]*|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*[_]|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z]([_]*[A-Za-z0-9]*)*)
INTEGER             (0|[0-9]+)
REAL                (0\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
WRONGNUMBER         ([0][0-9]+|[0][0-9]+[.][0-9]*|[.][0-9]+|[0-9]+[.])
OPERATOR            ([*/=])
SEPARATION          ([[\]{}\(\)])

%%

{NEWLINE}           { line_number++; }
{WHITESPACE}+       {}
{COMMENT}           {}

"program"           { return PROGRAM; }
"end"               { return END; }
"real"              { return REAL; }
"integer"           { return INTEGER; }
"void"              { return VOID; }
"return"            { return RETURN; }
{INTEGER}           { return INT_NUMBER; }
{REAL}              { return REAL_NUMBER; }
{WRONGNUMBER}       { illegalError(yytext, "Number"); }
","                 { return COMMA; }
";"                 { return SEMICOLON; }

{ID}                { return ID; }
{ILLEGALID}         { illegalError(yytext, "ID"); }

{OPERATOR}          { return yytext[0]; }
{SEPARATION}        { return yytext[0]; }

.                   { errorPrint(yytext[0]); }

%%

void initLexer() {
    line_number = 1;
    lexer_errors = 0;
    tokens = NULL;
    token = NULL;
}

void create_and_store_token(int kind, char *lexeme, int line) {
    if (token == NULL) {
        tokens = (YYSTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(YYSTYPE));
        token = tokens;
        token->next = NULL;
        token->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        token->next = (YYSTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(YYSTYPE));
        token->next->next = NULL;
        token->next->prev = token;
        token = token->next;
    }
    token->kind = kind;
    token->line = line;
    token->lexeme = (char *)malloc(sizeof(lexeme) + 1);
#ifdef _WIN32
    strcpy_s(token->lexeme, strlen(lexeme) + 1, lexeme);
#else
    strcpy(token->lexeme, lexeme);
#endif
}

YYSTYPE *next_token() {
    if (token) 
        return (token = token->next);
    return NULL;
}

YYSTYPE *back_token() {
    if (token) 
        return (token = token->prev);
    return NULL;
}

int match(int kind) {
    if (token && token->kind == kind) 
        return kind;
    return 0;
}

int type() {
    return (match(REAL) ? REAL : match(INTEGER));
}

int ar_op() {
    if (match('*') || match('/')) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int returned_type() {
    return (match(VOID) ? VOID : type());
}

int not_var_definitions() {
    int flag = 0;
    if (!token) 
        flag = 1;
    else if (match(ID)) {
        next_token();
        if (match('=') || match('('))
            flag = 2;

        if (match('[')) {
            next_token();
            next_token();
            next_token();
            if (match('=') || match('('))
                flag = 2;

            back_token();
            back_token();
            back_token();
        }
        back_token();
    }

    else 
        flag = 3;
    return flag;

}

int not_statements() {
    if (!token) 
        return 1;
    if (!match(ID) && !match(RETURN) && !match('{')) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void errorPrint(char ch) {
    fprintf(yyout, "The character '%c' at line: %d does not begin any legal token in the language.\n", ch, line_number);
}

void illegalError(const char *text, const char *type) {
    fprintf(yyout, "Illegal %s '%s' was found at line %d\n", type, text, line_number);
}
```

**However, I guess it's a rather cumbersome way to implement the parser.
How would edit my code, for using the technique of "recursive descent"?**
I know that in order to get it being used you need to perform a left recursion on the grammar, and the left common element is called. However, I find it difficult to apply it.

Comment: Why not writing a flex lexer and generate the code?

Comment: I did, but it's less relevant now...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He did https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242559/implementing-lexical-syntatic-and-semantic-analysis.

Comment: I'm curious why is the lexer less relevant now? Since no one has answered your first question yet you could add your updates to the question and remove this one, since it is almost a duplicate, or copy the relevant code here. I'd stick with the old question because that has an up vote. I'm in the process of reviewing the other one, but it's difficult and I can't get it to build. I have not installed win_flex yet and the code doesn't compile for me, especially semantic.c. It might also be better if you added your test case to the question and expected output.